# Can I screw directly into the iRobot Create 2 chassis rather than using the mounting holes indicated on the green cover?

Tags: irobot-create

Hi I'm trying to mount a few things to the iRobot Create 2 and I wanted to secure it to the robot in a better way than the holes indicated on the green cover! Because once I drill does holes, how am I actually going to secure anything to the cover and not drill into the plastic chassis underneath? Maybe heatsets would work but I hope that's not the solution because the green cover is quite thin. So After tearing the whole thing down a few times, I thought of using the existing screw holes for the chassis. I know that they are meant to be self-tapping plastic screws (thanks iRobot!!!) but I'm pretty sure I found the thread size for them which is No. 4 (https://www.mcmaster.com/99461a140). I just wanted to see if anyone has done this before and what kind of results they got by mounting right to the chassis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may have answered your own question here, but in case you're looking for reassurance, I don't see any reason why you couldn't use the bosses that already exist; iRobot provides their locations [here](https://www.irobotweb.com/-/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/iRobotCreate2-ScrewBossLocations.pdf). I have seen projects where others use them, though I usually use inserts pressed into the cover, or else 3D-print a replacement bin. If you do use the existing bosses, be careful not to strip them, since as you pointed out, they're self-tapping screws. I suppose if you were feeling adventurous, you could take the top cover off and replace some of the bosses with heat set machine screw inserts...

<sup>Please note that I am an iRobot employee, but the postings on this site are my own and don't necessarily represent iRobot's positions, strategies, or opinions.</sup>

Comment: Hey Steve, I was hoping you'd be the one answering this! I had no idea that others have used the bosses so yes I was kind of asking for reassurance. Also thanks a lot for the document. It's a great help. After reading some of the other posts about the weight capacity of the creat I had to make a lot of changes. I'm trying to put a 150cm stand on top of the thing. So to take its weight off the robot I'm trying to make a platform with wheels that takes on the weight n then sits on the roomba. That way roomba is only dragging it! I know it's a bit ballsy!

Comment: Also could you please guide me to where I can find more files with technical info like this one. Because I've looked all over the place for the location of these bosses but I could never find them. I wonder if there are other files out there that could be of immense help that I haven't been able to find!

Comment: Hi Amin; happy to help! :) All of the technical info (including the boss locations) can be found here: https://www.irobot.com/about-irobot/stem/create-2/projects ; the first row of links (including "More") will get you to a lot of technical info. Best of luck with your project, and please be sure to share your successes (and keep asking questions when you run into difficulties)!